# Replace the Categories whit their Id´s

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, for-loop

So, in one hand, I have onE table that have categories and all categories have a specific Id. In the other hand, I have a dataframe whit all products, and each product have a categorie.

What I want is to change the category name to is exact Id, in the Dataframe

```
 dict_categorias = {}

    for tuplo in IdCat:
       dict_categorias[tuplo[0]] = tuplo[1]
       for index,row in tabela_new.iterrows():
           if(row['Categoria']==dict_categorias[tuplo[1]]):   
               tabela_new.at[index,'Categoria'] = dict_categorias[tuplo[0]]
```

The table is like this

```
1: 'TUBO',
2: 'LEITOR',
3: 'ANTENA',
4: 'POE',
```

And the dataframe :

```
    Data      Código de barras  Categoria   Valor Uni (€)
 0  2022-12-31  5415306102467   LEITOR      NaN
 1  2022-12-31  3662211007819   CAIXA       NaN
```

I tried to create a dictionary for the table categories, and compare the categorie of the product to the categorie in table categories, and if the categories are equal it change for the Id of the categorie

In the code above the tuplo[0] is the Id and tuplo[1] is the categorie

It seems a little complicaded, the code above isn´t working and i dont know any other way to do it. Can anyone help me ?!!

Comment: can you show us a sample of how your table of categories and the df with the products look like?

Comment: It's all a bit unclear what you want precisely (since you a list of 2-tuples, apparently), but if you turn `IdCat` into a dict (`dict(IdCat)` may be enough), you can probably do this in one go with [Pandas `map` utility](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `map` after reverse your table:

```
IdCat = {1: 'TUBO', 2: 'MEMÓRIA', 3: 'ANTENA', 4: 'POE', 5: 'LEITORN', 6: 'CAIXA'}
IdCat_rev = {v: k for k, v in IdCat.items()}

tabela_new['Categoria_num'] = tabela_new['Categoria'].map(IdCat_rev)
```

Output:

```
>>> tabela_new
         Data  Código de barras Categoria  Valor Uni (€)  Categoria_num
0  2022-12-31     5415306102467   LEITORN            NaN              5
1  2022-12-31     3662211007819     CAIXA            NaN              6

>>> IdCat_rev
{'TUBO': 1, 'MEMÓRIA': 2, 'ANTENA': 3, 'POE': 4, 'LEITORN': 5, 'CAIXA': 6}
```

Missing values in dictionary will be set to `NaN`.